# Complex SQL Server query to LINQ to SQL query C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm new to linq to sql and I have some complex SQL query.

My SQL Server query does this shortly: I have 2 tables, product (a) and productorder (b). Product has amount and a second amount which warns the customer how many items still in progress.

In "a" we have 10 papers if we order 5. Then table a second amount value is 5. If we order more :  5 = 5 + more

So I write my T-SQL here. I want a linq to sql

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.secondamount = a.secondamount + b.orderedamount 
INNER JOIN b ON a.productid == b.productid 
WHERE b.status = false ;
```

Comment: You Write already a SQL Query. Do You want to translate this to LINQ?

Comment: Yes , this code snippet what i used in my old program. Right now i have to replace every sqlcommand/reader etc to linq to sql. I almost replaced everything i stucked with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is not used for updating but for **querying**. You can use linq to find all the records you want to update and prepare the data but then the update itself should happen separately.

```
var result = from itemA in a
             join itemB in b on itemA.productId equals itemB.productId
             where itemB.Status == false
             select new { itemA, itemB.orderedamount };

foreach(var item in result)
{
    //do update using item.itemA.secondAmount + item.orderedamount
}
```

Comment: Gilad, sorry, tried to make your query compilable and introduced another silly mistake.

Comment: I meant I broke your answer with my first edit, so I apologize for that.

Comment: @IvanStoev - ahh ok ya got it. The `equals` was just a silly mistake :) haha. About the `join` compared to the `where` - I know the `join` is the correct one in terms of how the original sql but what will happen if that join yields more than one record?.. that is why I changed it to the `Any`

Comment: Well, specifically in this case I was not thinking for performance or cardinality, but only that you need `itemB` inside the `select` :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev - och of course haha stupid me. I did it with the join initially and then changed without checking haha :) thanks for the edit

Comment: @bencemik95 - Did this help you understand what you should do to correct your approach?

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i think its gonna work for me, i have one more question, what should i write into foreach to update my column also there will be multiple rows changed at the same time

Comment: @bencemik95 - not sure. Didn't have to do that for a long time. If you'll look online I'm sure there'll be many questions on that

Comment: *simple* <br/>simple